# get value of select in cell datatable jquery

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable with some data. I also add a select element in cells.

```
$('#tableComponent').dataTable({
    "info": false,
    "bLengthChange": false, //used to hide the property 
    "aaData": objJson,
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mData": "componentID.productID"
    }, {
        "mData": "componentID.productName"
    }, {
        "mData": null,
        'mRender': function(o) {
            return '<select class="form-control"><option value="1">Stock 1</option><option value="2">Stock 2</option></select>';
        }
    }, {
        "mData": "quantity"
    }, {
        "mData": "unitPrice"
    }, {
        "mData": "total"
    }]
});
```

And now, I want to get the value of the option that has been selected. 
Can you help me resolve this?
Thanks you so much!

Comment: Create your select in pure javascript fashion (`document.createElement('select')`) Add all your options to your new select element. And finally bind an `onchange` event to get the value of option once selected.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. But I want to get array value of selected per row.

Comment: Did I understood you correctly: You want to get the value of every select in your datatable ?

Comment: yes, I want to get value of selected option every row in my datatable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
myTable.column(5).nodes().each(function (node, index, dt) {
  alert($(myTable.cell(node).node()).find('select.form-control').val());
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/s8JmF/329/**

However, for this to work you have to initialize datatables like this

```
$('#test').DataTable({..});
```

instead of

```
$('#test').dataTable({..});
```

Notice the uppercase `D`